# Blender Brush doesn´t work in Ocean Modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface, dynamic-paint, shrinkwrap, ocean-simulation

I just get stuck with what is actually probably a simple matter. I'm relatively new to Blender, so maybe I just overlooked something small here. I have a ship on an ocean that should leave a trail in the water while driving. To do this, I marked the ocean and created a Dynamic Paint and set Surface Type to Waves. The same for the ship, but as a brush. I attached a link to the file. When the ship goes, nothing happens. How can that be?

[Blender File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhbi7gaq8hz32qf/Ocean.blend?dl=0)

I would really appreciate your help!

Best regards,
Tim

Comment: next time pleeeeease reduce your blend file. For people with low internet speeds loading 284 MB files is not funny.

Comment: Oh ok I´m sorry  I thought that I'd rather use the whole file to be on the safe side.

Comment: kein Problem - aber ist echt langsam... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, i don't know why it does not work, but i have some tips for you.

1. Fake it 'til you make it:
   Do not use your ship to create the waves - it has to much details, too complicated. Just slows down your computer - although i am not sure whether you are working on a render farm, because your blend file is so fully packed and on my macbook i got 0.1 fps with your settings....
   So i just build a quick mesh like this to create the waves:

[image]

2. first try out with very simple models/blend - files, whether your "idea"/concept works at all...

test: https://youtu.be/jhXz2EItvZ4

check, works

3. try to adapt your model in that way....

so i deleted your brush and added the super simple model from 1 to your blend file

4. added some movement by adding keyframes

-> that's what i learned from this time consuming "session": copy location does NOT work together with dynamic paint. Don't ask me why. I have no clue. But it works if you animate via keyframes. I guess that's why dynamic paint never worked with your ship because it is also moved via copy location.

5. result: (of course you should hide the primitive model and tweak the settings so that it is looking good. My waves are shitty, i just wanted to show that it works)

https://youtu.be/qFZQnPT3q9I

and this is how it looks without the "simple model", so the ship is really making the waves -> is just deleted the copylocation modifiers and animated it by keyframe.

Result:

https://youtu.be/vuQTpul-YHM

and rendered it looks like this (ok, boat was too quick ;))

https://youtu.be/musNu7EPj1Y

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to watch this! Hmm really strange, I honestly don't know exactly why the file is so big. After all, half were the textures. But apart from that, I actually only have the ocean and the ship there. The island in the background doesn't take that much power away. The ocean kind of takes so much power away...

Did you mean that I should then put the simple model over the right ship or how exactly? 
Do you maybe still have the edited file to look at it for me? 

Comment: yes, that's what i meant.

Comment: i updated my answer -> send me your email, then i send you the updated blend file

Comment: Hello Chris i sent you an Email. Thank you so much for all the help!!! 